# Product Stock -1

Tags: magento-1.7, inventory, out-of-stock

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have configured my store not to allow backorders, but for some reason some products are ordered having the stock at 0.

I'm using Paypal for the payment process.

Catalog -> Inventory Settings:

- Decrease Stock When Order is Placed => Yes
- Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled => Yes
- Display Out of Stock Products => Yes
- Only X left Threshold => 0
- Manage Stock => Yes
- Backorders => No Backorders

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48015/out-of-stock-products-still-appear-in-the-frontend?rq=1

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48015/out-of-stock-products-still-appear-in-the-frontend?rq=1 is not helpfull, since my catalog is configurable products.
The out of stock products dont appear on the store, but for some reason someone was able to order one of the out of stock products.